# Given record key type, infer record value type

Tags: typescript

I don’t know if it’s possible but my objective is: Given the type of the record key, I want to automatically infer the type of the value when using a function:

```
type Dog = 'dog';
type Cat = 'cat';
type Animal = Dog | Cat;

enum AnimalType {
  Dog,
  Cat,
}

const animalMap = {
  [AnimalType.Dog]: 'dog',
  [AnimalType.Cat]: 'cat',
} as const;

const getAnimal = (type: AnimalType) => animalMap[type];

const dog = getAnimal(AnimalType.Dog); // type: 'dog' | 'cat'. desired type: 'dog'
const cat = animalMap[AnimalType.Cat]; // type: 'cat'
```

I want to use the function above instead of using directly the map. It is a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to keep track of the specific subtype of `AnimalType` passed into `getAnimal()`, you want
`getAnimal()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type.  If `type` is just of type `AnimalType` then that's all the compiler knows about it.  Instead you want it to be of generic type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `AnimalType`:

```
const getAnimal = <T extends AnimalType>(type: T) => animalMap[type];

const dog = getAnimal(AnimalType.Dog); // type: 'dog'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigcgCaLQbgFCiRQDCAhsCugMbm4HjQCCAdgJYC2pANpfEgD4ly+PBGYBXdlBYduAFQZQA3niixEAGlVDgWgL548VOMwDOFUm05cAsqTCUVagNozrCyADo+AXQBc6FgIaFoubvIMnmTA-tS0+lCkplDGZsAiqeZQCBDA4TyoADxyUBAAHsBiGMn5HhAAfAAUhBABcgCUKPWJVtx2YM4tPhkmWUGUOXm9XI21kXztOFAA9MtQLQGY2HhAA)